# Serialize Entity Collection in XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization

i m trying to serialize an object that holds entitycollection in it. i can do simple serialization using

```
     public string Serialize<T>(T item)
      {
          XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true });
        try
        {
            mySerializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            sww.Close();
        }
        return sww.ToString();
    }
```

i m using Entity Framework and my object that i want to serialize contains a EntityCollection and when i try to serialize object it do serialize but miss Entity collection part. and when i try to see in object using VS inspector it shows me - Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable.that seems i need to explicity add the values to object that will be seralized i did that yet it didnt work

```
Workflow wfi = wf; //assigning entity object to wfi so it can be serialized
foreach (var intials in wf.FieldsInfo) {   wfi.FieldsInfo.Add(intials);    }
```

object that need to be serialized is wfi.  any help wil be appreciated  to make it bit more clear this EntityCollection is a navigation property 
can we serialize object + navigation property together or i need to define a new class that compose object and navigation property(entity collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can turn off the lazy loading for the entity model. That way it will force the loading off all fields.

To do that you can try to go the EDMX properties and put lazy loading off.

Other thing you can try is the "include", like this:

```
myEntity.MyTable.include("FieldsInfo");
```

Only after that pass the item to the Serialize method. This can have a problem if you have circular references...

Comment: i already using this approach. but it didnt worked the way i wanted or as u suggested so i solved in other way i defined a class and then assign entity collection to class property and then serialized the class object. it worked but drawback of this approach was i need to define a new class dat i didnt wanted nyhow thanku for commenting

Comment: Ok :) Anyway, it's always a good pratice to have the POCO instead of the entity that is generated in by the EF. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works fine.
 In the Partial class of the entity I add a Property that returns a list of the EntityColleciton, as follow:

```
public List<XXX> XXXList // XXX stands for the EntityCollection
{
    get { return XXX.ToList; }
}
```

The serialzer gets the object correctly with all relations.